# Issues in working with comparison operators

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement which looks like:

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` > '850' AND `scaleble` < '1200' )
```

and is not producing any results, whereas another SQL statement which looks like:

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` > 850 AND `scaleble` < 1200 )
```

gives required results.

However, the individual comparisons like:

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` > '850')
```

AND

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` < '1200')
```

do produce the required results. 
I am a bit confused with the working of these queries. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think you should not put quotes around your integers in a SQL Query.

Comment: What is the type of `scaleble` ?

Comment: It is of type varchar(255)

Comment: @Tushki check my posted answer which will return different records for each query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `scalable` is being stored as a string.  The comparisons with single quotes convert the values to strings, so they are not numerically ordered.  As string `'850' > '1200'` so nothing satisfies the condition.

You can fix this by dropping the single quotes.  I would also encourage you to convert the value to a number explicitly.  I often just add `0` for this purpose:

```
SELECT `scaleble`
FROM `property_requirement`
WHERE (`scaleble` + 0 > 850 AND `scaleble` + 0 < 1200 );
```

Comment: But why are the individual queries working then? And that too in the expected fashion..

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong to test please check <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2026/5)</kbd>

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` > '850')
```

This above query will return only next higher value record. Where following query will return all higer record

```
SELECT `scaleble` FROM `property_requirement` WHERE (`scaleble` > 850)
```

Compare these two queries in fiddle

Comment: But in my case I am getting multiple values from the former query as well but yes, the count is different.